# Linux Container : bash : lxc command not found

Tags: linux

I'm following this linux tut. At stage :

lxc restore first clean

I got error :  bash : lxc command not found

Can I fix it somehow ?

[image]

Comment: Dumb question - do you have lxc installed?

Comment: Second dumb question - if it's installed have you added it to your path?